# Register service worker

Tags: backbone.js, service-worker

I'd like to register service worker for my application.

```
this.addEventListener('install', function(event) {
            event.waitUntil(
              caches.open('v1').then(function(cache) {
                return cache.addAll([
                  '/css/main.css',
                  '/index.html',

                  '/js/views/game.js',
                  '/js/views/main.js',
                  '/js/views/scoreboard.js',
                  '/js/views/viewManager.js',

                  '/js/main.js',
                  '/js/router.js',              
                  '/js/service-worker.js',

                  '/static/snakes.jpg',
                  '/static/field.jpg',

                  // '/#main',
                  // '/#scoreboard',
                  // '/#game',
                ]);
              })
            );
          });
```

I have trouble with the urls that contain hashes. I'm using backbone js and I don't like to change urls with hashes on simple urls. How can I add url with hash in cache?

Answer (score 4):

Currently fragment identifiers are ignored by the cache. See https://github.com/slightlyoff/ServiceWorker/issues/854 and https://github.com/whatwg/fetch/issues/214.

In the [service workers specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/service-workers/), all the methods of the Cache contain the step `Set r's url's fragment to null.` (see for example the [Cache.matchAll method](https://www.w3.org/TR/service-workers/#cache-matchall-method)).